# Can't save matplotlib figure to jpeg (it is blank) in jupiter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, save, figure

I can't save my figure to jpeg (or any other) file (it is blank)

```
x=list(df2['DAYTIME'])
z=list(df2['av100002 - temp Wywiew'])
x3= x[::75]


fig1 = plt.figure()
axes1 = fig1.add_axes([0,30,3.5,1.4])
axes1.set_title('Nawiew')


axes1.plot(x,z, lw=3)

axes1.set_xticks(x3)  

plt.xticks(x3, rotation=60)
fig1.savefig('xx.png', dpi=200)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: no, the file is just blank

Comment: Why the `list()` in `list(df2['DAYTIME'])` and `list(df2['av100002 - temp Wywiew'])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of your axes is wrong and puts the axes off figure.

try `axes1 = fig1.add_subplot()` for a quick fix, which [creates an axes centered in the figure space](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot).

If you want to use `add_axes()` for manual placement of the axes, then [the coordinates are given in figure fractions](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes). The coordinate are [left, bottom, width, height] where 0 represent the left/bottom edge of the figure and 1 the right/top edge of the figure.

by default `fig.add_subplot()` is equivalent to `fig.add_axes([0.125, 0.11, 0.9, 0.88])`

Full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure()
axes1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
axes1.set_title('Nawiew')
fig1.savefig('xx.png', dpi=200)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replay. I am a rookie and i dont know where to put 'axes1 = fig1.add_subplot()' in my code, can you help?

Comment: replace the line `axes1 = fig1.add_axes([0,30,3.5,1.4])` with `axes1 = fig1.add_subplot()`

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-e2895d21608f> in <module>
      2 
      3 axes1 = fig1.add_subplot()
----> 4 axes1.set_title('Nawiew')
      5 
      6 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_title'

Comment: I've added a full code that produces a plot. Please run it as it is written. If that does not work then you need to provide a full [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It dose not work when i paste it
this is my error this time

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-39617566264a> in <module>
      3 fig1 = plt.figure()
      4 axes1 = fig1.add_subplot()
----> 5 axes1.set_title('Nawiew')
      6 fig1.savefig('xxx.png', dpi=200)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_title'

Comment: can you try to write `fig1.add_subplot(111)` instead of `fig1.add_subplot()`

Comment: yeah, it is working, but how can i manipulate the plot size ?

Comment: This https://towardsdatascience.com/the-fundamentals-of-matplotlib-10b742e3616b seems like a good tutorial. Also look at the gallery / tutorials on the matplotlib website https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html

Answer (score -1):

ok i figure it out

`
    fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1,figsize=(30,3.5))

```
axes.plot(x,z)


plt.grid()
plt.xticks(x3, rotation=60)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('xx.png', dpi=200)
```

`
thanks for your help